# Travel from Cairo to Romania via schengen visa

Tags: schengen, romania, egyptian-citizens

I am Egyptian, and I have multiple-entry Schengen visa from France which I already used few weeks ago. Now I need to travel to Romania and I need to know if I can travel directly from Cairo to Romania via my Schengen visa or I have to enter first a Schengen state then to travel to Romania. Also I want to know if I traveled from Cairo to Romania through Frankfurt, will my passport be stamped at Frankfurt ?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to know if I can travel directly from Cairo to Romania via my
>   schengen visa or I have to enter first a schengen state then to travel
>   to Romania.

You can travel directly to Romania; assuming you have not violated the 90/180 rule for Schengen visas, your visa is valid for the duration of your stay, and your passport is also valid for the duration of your stay.

> Also I want to know if i traveled from Cairo to Romania thru transit
>   at Frankfurt, will my passport be stamped at Frankfurt?

Yes, it will be stamped as this is your point of entry into the Schengen zone; even if you are on transit.

Comment: If you are traveling from outside the Schengen zone to Romania and your only stop within the Schengen zone is Frankfurt, I think you will stay in international transit and your passport will not be stamped, (but I have never done it myself.)

Comment: @Willeke Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to correct the answer above:

> Also I want to know if i traveled from Cairo to Romania thru transit
>   at Frankfurt, will my passport be stamped at Frankfurt?

No, it will not be stamped IF you fly Cairo-Frankfurt-Otopeni. Romania is not part of Shenghen, so you will not go through passport control in Frankfurt. You will go through passport control in Romania only. Have done it myself.

Comment: but i will enter romania with no issue?

Comment: so i can travel to romania with a direct flight and no need to travel first to a schengen state?

Comment: The answer is "yes". However as far as I know, there are no direct flights between Cairo and Bucharest yet, and your best option would likely be flying through Athens. Please let me know if you find a direct one.